# Angular 8 - Apply multi-tenant

Tags: angular, angular-material, themes, angular8

I am working in a project for multiple clients. I am using angular themes for change the background color, font, etc for the different clients and I have to reuse the components changing the different text of each section depending on the client(I get the client from the server). Is there any easy way to do that?

At the same time I have to translate the text to different languages so any help of both things will be appreciate.

Comment: I have the same problem, especially regarding internationalization (i18n).  There's the built-in Angular solution as well as nice 3rd party libraries like transloco, but everything seems focused around just picking a translation file for the culture the site is running in.  I can't find any way to have another step in the process where two different sites built from the same solution can use the same culture, but different translation files.  Or even better, use a base set of files for that culture, but let them override certain terms.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you heard of `environnement variables` but it might be great to use them in your case, depending on the options you'll give to **ng serve** example : **ng serve --client1** you can automaticly change variables you defined, here's how it looks : https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/

Comment: your answer could work but not in my case. I need change the footer, content, header, etc texts of the whole application for each client